# "XML Parsing Error: junk after document element"

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, xml-parsing

Hey everyone I'm trying to display a Google map with dynamic locations retrieve from database I was following [developers.google.com/maps/articles on phpsqlajax_v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3).I created the database and the table looks like this

**trnsportpublic table**

transportpublicid  int 11 AUTOINCREMENT

transportType      varchar 60

costPerKm          decimal(7,2)

address            varchar 800

teleNo             int 10

webLink            varchar 300

description        varchar 800

lat                double(10,6)

lng                double(10,6)

---

**GenerateXml.php**

```
 <?php

          require("db_connection.php");


          function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
          { 
              $xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
              $xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
              $xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
              $xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); // line 11  
              $xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
              return $xmlStr; 
          } 

          // Select all the rows in the markers table
          $query = "SELECT transportType,costPerKm,address,teleNo,webLink,lat,lng FROM transportpublic";

          $result = mysql_query($query);
          if (!$result) 
          {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
          }

          header("Content-type: text/xml");

          // Start XML file, echo parent node
          echo '<transportpublic>';

          // Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
            echo '<marker ';
            echo 'transportType="' . parseToXML($row['transportType']) . '" ';
            echo 'costPerKm="' . $row['costPerKm'] . '" ';
            echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
            echo 'teleNo="' . $row['teleNo'] . '" ';
            echo 'webLink="' . parseToXML($row['webLink']) . '" ';
            echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
            echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
            echo '/>';
          }

          // End XML file
          echo '</transportpublic>';
    ?>
```

When I run **GenerateXml.php** on browser is gives me fillowing

```
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: http://localhost:8080/testserver/generateXml.php
Line Number 11, Column 8:
</html>
<transportpublic>
<marker transportType="Bus" costPerKm="1.50" address="abc" teleNo="112554476" webLink="http://www.abc.html" lat="0.000000" lng="0.000000" />

<marker transportType="Train" costPerKm="12.00" address="abc" teleNo="118745963" webLink="http://www.abc.html" lat="0.000000" lng="0.000000" />

<marker transportType="hmmmm" costPerKm="40.00" address="abc" teleNo="112541254" webLink="http://www.abc.html" lat="-33.005985" lng="-58.501824" />

<marker transportType="test" costPerKm="2.00" address="abc" teleNo="112541258" webLink="http://www.abc.html" lat="39.785999" lng="-75.041976" />

<marker transportType="test2" costPerKm="2.00" address="abc" teleNo="112541254" webLink="http://www.abc.html" lat="6.901698" lng="79.853854" />

</transportpublic>
-------^
```

---

I only got to know that after the root element I shouldn't be parsing any data it'll be taken as junk but in my GenerateXml.php i don't do anything after this line

```
echo '</transportpublic>';
```

---

help me please.

Comment: You should really use PHP's DOM functions to create your XML.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `</html>` does not belong here.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario  thank you sir you pointed me to the correct direction i double cheked .php files but missed "db_connection.php" it had <html> <?php mysql database connection stuff ?> </html> in it and i removed html tags and now it works :) sir why not make it an answer.. thanks everyone for your time and effort appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root node is `<transportpublic>` but the error message shows a bogus `</html>` close tag right before it. The XML parser probably thinks that `<html>` is the root node, thus the rest of the XML is the *junk after document element* mentioned by the error.