# XML Parsing Error: junk after document element. not dump </kurz> i have no idea

Tags: php, xml

```
<?php

  $dotaz=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Jazykove_kurzy`");

  $b="</kurz>\n";

if($dotaz) while($data = mysql_fetch_array($dotaz)) {

 $kod = "<kurz ID=\"$data[ID]\">         
    <jazyk>$data[jazyk]</jazyk>
    <pocet>$data[pocet]</pocet>
    <rozsah>$data[rozsah]</rozsah>
    <mesto>$data[mesto]</mesto>
    <cena>$data[cena]</cena>
    <lektori>$data[lektori]</lektori>
    <platnost>$data[platnost]</platnost>";
```

There is problem... when it write `$b` to `$soubor`, I have error

```
fwrite($soubor, $kod);
fwrite($soubor, $b);
}
fclose($soubor);

    ?>
```

I have no idea. Please help.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of ["XML Parsing Error: junk after document element"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762857/xml-parsing-error-junk-after-document-element)

Comment: Sorry i dont understand this. I have to see on code...

Comment: Hi Karel, your PHP-code seems incomplete, I'd like to see the generated XML, too. The way you create the XML is unsafe and vulnerable to errors, so use a parser like `SimpleXML` or `DOM instead`.